# Issues running ubuntu 15.10 on Acer r3 131t acpi need to be of

Tags: boot, acer, cpu, acpi

I am trying to install ubuntu 15.10 on my acer R3 131T. I have run in to several problems, most of which where easy to fix. However there is this one problem i can't seem to get by. I can not boot the system without the following markers: acpi=off noapic.

I think it has something to do with the CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N3150  @ 1.60GHz

Does anybody have a solution for this problem. Because running it without acpi is not an option since only one core will work and the battery information would not be available.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I sort of found the solution in the meantime. I am able to run with all cores and with acpi on in linux kernel 3.19.0-26, however in this older kernels there is no support yet for my intel wireless and the touchpad wil not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the need for noapic and apci=off with my Acer R3 131t for a Ubuntu 15.10 install, required me to boot back into Windows, and do a Firmware / BIOS update from the Acer webpage. (I forget the software version number, maybe going from version 1.6 to 1.9. They put it out in August 2015 I believe.)

Comment: Thank you that worked. For the record the latest bios that works for now is version 1.09.